# Clang libFuzzer Undefined Reference to `__sanitizer_cov_trace_const_cmp8'

Tags: c, nginx, makefile, clang

I can successfully compile Nginx with the following variables in the makefile

`CC =    clang-6.0`

`CFLAGS =  -pipe  -O -Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g`

When attempting to use -fsanitize=fuzzer or -fsanitize=fuzzer-no-link and changing my Makefile to:

`CFLAGS =  -pipe -fsantizer=fuzzer-no-link -O -Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g`

I get numerous undefined references to `__sancov_lowest_stack` and to `__sanitizer_cov_trace_const_cmp8`

How would I fix this? Which libraries am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add sanitizer flags like `-fsanitize=fuzzer` to your `CFLAGS` **and** your `LDFLAGS`.

If they aren't passed to the linker but just to the compiler you get tons of undefined symbol errors for sanitizer runtime library functions (like the one you quoted in your question).

Note that when using `-fsanitizer=fuzzer` it makes sense to combine it with the Adress Sanitizer (i.e. `-fsanitizer=fuzzer,address`).

Also, with libFuzzer, you [have to provide your own fuzzer callback function](http://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html) `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput()` and omit a `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against honggfuzz/libhfuzz/libhfuzz.a.

Comment: No, you don't. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722009/427158).